# PHP: Merge arrays in 2-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, merge

How can I merge the second and the third, the fourth and the fifth, the sixth and the seventh, ... values of a 2-dimensional array? The first array [number] should not be merged:

```
Array
(
[number] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1234
        [1] => 2345
        [2] => 3456
    )
[vote01] => Array
    (
        [0] => 000
        [1] => 000
        [2] => 001
    )
[vote02] => Array
    (
        [0] => 002
        [1] => 002
        [2] => 003
    )
[vote03] => Array
    (
        [0] => 004
        [1] => 004
        [2] => 005
    )
[vote04] => Array
    (
        [0] => 006
        [1] => 007
        [2] => 008
    )
    ...
)
```

merged to:

```
Array
(
[number] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1234
        [1] => 2345
        [2] => 3456
    )
[new01] => Array
    (
        [0] => 000
        [1] => 000
        [2] => 001
        [3] => 002
        [4] => 002
        [5] => 003
    )
[new02] => Array
    (
        [0] => 004
        [1] => 004
        [2] => 005
        [3] => 006
        [4] => 007
        [5] => 008
    )
    ...
)
```

I need somehow combine the `array_merge_recursive()` function and the `foreach` loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using array_walk:

```
array_walk($arr, function($item, $key, &$d) {
    if ($d[0]++ > 1 && $d[0] % 2) {
        $end = &$d[1][count($d[1]) - 1];
        $end = array_merge($end, $item);
    }
    else {
        $d[1][] = $item;
    }
}, array(0, &$newarr));
```

And here's a working [demo](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/kis-06h).